# CakePHP Redirecting to the View page after adding a new record

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a CakePHP lead management website, and when you make a new lead, I want it to redirect you to the view page for that lead, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my current add controller.

```
    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $lead = $this->Leads->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $lead = $this->Leads->patchEntity($lead, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Leads->save($lead)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The lead has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The lead could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
          }
        }
        $this->set(compact('lead'));
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }
```

The line that I am conserned about is `return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);`.

For the edit controller, I was able to do `return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $id]);` but that doesn't work here, and I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.  If it matters, IDs are just a sequential counter in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $lead = $this->Leads->newEmptyEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $lead = $this->Leads->patchEntity($lead, $this->request->getData());
            if ($savedLead = $this->Leads->save($lead)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The lead has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $savedLead->id]);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The lead could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('lead'));
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }
```

Here, you need to set a variable containing the result of recording you saved (**savedLead** in your case). This variable will contain the **id** of the newly saved recording, and you can pass it to your **view** method.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem with

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $lead->id]);
```

?